# How to define regexp for text in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

Please help to define Postgres regexp for this case:

I have string field:

```
union all select 'AbC-345776-2345' /*comment*/ union all select 'Fgr-sdf344-111a' /*BN34*/ some text union all select 'sss-sdf34-123' /*some text*/ some text
```

Here is the same text in select statement for convinience:

```
select 'union all select ''AbC-345776-2345'' /*comment*/ union all select ''Fgr-sdf344-111a'' /*BN34*/ some text union all select ''sss-sdf34-123'' /*some text*/ some text' as str
```

I need to get from this mess text only values in '...' and select it into separated rows like this:

```
AbC-345776-2345
Fgr-sdf344-111a
sss-sdf34-123
```

Pattern: 'first 2-3 letters - several letters and numbers - several letters and numbers'

I created this select but it contains all comments and "sometext" as well:

```
select regexp_split_to_table(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(t1.str,'union all select',''),'from DUAL',''),chr(10),''),'''','') ), E'\\s+')
from (select 'union all select ''AbC-345776-2345'' /*comment*/ union all select ''Fgr-sdf344-111a'' /*BN34*/ some text union all select ''sss-sdf34-123'' /*some text*/ some text' as str) t1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
select (regexp_matches(str, $$'([a-zA-Z]{2,3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)'$$, 'g'))[1]
from the_table;
```

Given your sample data it returns:

```
regexp_matches 
---------------
AbC-345776-2345
Fgr-sdf344-111a
sss-sdf34-123
```

The regex checks for the pattern you specified inside single quotes. By using a group `(...)` I excluded the single quotes from the result.

`regexp_matches()` returns one row for each match, containing an array of matches. But as the regex only contains a single group, the first element of the array is what we are interested in.

I used [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to avoid escaping the single quotes in the regex

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=09a81ba91fe6ad832fabaec615b38a1b)